# Puppet 6.1.0: node.rb missing from installed files?

Tags: linux, puppet, ubuntu-18.04

For testing, I have installed two instances of Ubuntu server 18.04 on VirtualBox. I then installed one with Puppet-server 6.1.0 and one with Puppet-agent 6.1.0, as per the documentation at Puppetlabs for version 6.1. Foreman is **not** installed.

After registering my agent at the puppetserver and signing the certificate, starting a puppet-run (sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent --test) fails with the following error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Failed when searching for node puppetagent.fritz.box: Exception while executing '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/node.rb': Cannot run program "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/node.rb" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I was dumbstruck to find that the script /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/node.rb was indeed missing and was also not included in the packages of puppetserver, puppet-agent or facter (sudo dpkg-query -L ...).

Googling for it, I only found a script of the same name that belonged to Foreman.

The file does also not seem to be present in the puppetserver source-code at github.

Is anyone able to shed some light on this?

Comment: To be more precise: There are multiple files called "node.rb" on the puppetserver-system (in /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/... and /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/...). None of them are the right script though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server configuration seems to be set up to specify use of an external node classifier. This is optional: Puppet does not require an ENC and does not provide one by default. That's part of what makes them "external".  If you obtained the result you describe straight out of the box then it probably reflects a packaging flaw that you should report.

In the meantime, you should be able to update [the configuration](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.1/nodes_external.html#connecting-an-enc) to disable use of an ENC by changing the value of the `node_terminus` setting to `plain`.  Alternatively, you should be able to just delete both `node_terminus` and `external_nodes` from your configuration, because the default for the former is `plain`.

Comment: You are right (It was my mistake). After posting this question, to get the puppetserver  working, I installed Foreman. I just reverted the VM to a snapshot before the Foreman installation and checked the puppet.conf. It seems that I copied the puppet.conf from a system with an installed Foreman and this inadvertently introduced "external_nodes = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/node.rb". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Tagging on to John's answer, your configuration *is* probably configured to talk to the Foreman. If you didn't write it yourself or copy it from somewhere and you're sure you don't have any Foreman packages installed, then it's definitely a packaging error that you should report.

That said, [puppet repos](https://puppet.com/docs/puppetserver/latest/install_from_packages.html) are almost always the right answer rather than distro packages.

Comment: I did use the official puppet repos and not the distro packages, but John's answer was right. Thank you too though.